# Select arrays from a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I work with python and I have a really basic question.
I an array of 1000 elements. I want to select 100 positions of this array.
I want to do something like

```
     selected_value=array[i for i in position_to_select]
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have the list `arr`, from which you want to select elements at positions 0, 4, 2:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> selected = [arr[i] for i in [0, 4, 2]]
>>> selected
[1, 5, 3]
>>>
```

I think that the key difference with your original code sample is using `arr[i]` in the list comprehension. A list comprehension creates a new list. It is not used to index an existing list.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to select all the elements that do not belong to a list? I tried with selected = [arr[i] for i not in [0, 4, 2]], but I got an invalid syntax error.

Comment: @Matteo: the most efficient way would be to compute the list of indexes in advance and then use the same code. In advance computation can be arbitrary, such as indexes that don't fulfill a certain predicate

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> selected_value = [array[i] for i in position_to_select]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work often with large arrays, have a look at [**numpy**](https://numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([3., 4., 3., 7., 3., 6., 9., 1., 2., 5.])
position_to_select = [1, 3, 6]

selected_value = arr[position_to_select]

# array([ 4.,  7.,  9.])
```